# Reset variable javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a variable when you click a button , and reset it when you release the button :

```
    var outputEl    = document.getElementById('result');

var click1 = document.getElementById("Button1");
click1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    funarr('1');
});

var click2 = document.getElementById("Button2");
click2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    funarr('2');
});

function funarr(value){
    arrow = value ;
    outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> ' + arrow;
}
```

I tried with :

```
    function funarr(value){
    arrow = value ;
    outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> ' + arrow;
    setTimeout(function(){arrow = 0 ;},100);
    outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> ' + arrow;
}
```

but it doesn't work , and doesn't resolve my problem too, because I need to reset the variable only when you release the button , not after a time lapse

withou luck . how can I do this?

EDIT : solved using onmouseup and onmousedown

```
    var outputEl    = document.getElementById('result');

var click1 = document.getElementById("Button1");
click1.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    funarr('1');
});

click1.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    funarr('0');
});

function funarr(value){
    arrow = value ;
    outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> ' + arrow;
}
```

thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, a `click` event is the combination of pressing and releasing a mouse button. It sounds like you want to listen for the `mousedown` event for when they click the button and the `mouseup` event for when they release it.

Comment: so , using mouseup and mousedown is more correct than click right ?

Comment: In this case, yes. More generally, it depends on what you want to do - a lot of times, the standard click is what you're interested in.

Comment: I solved it using mousedown/up for non touc and touchstart and touchend for touch device

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery (too much writing in vanilla js ;) ):

```
var outputEl = $('#result');

$('#Button1').mousedown(function() { funarr('1') });
$('#Button2').mousedown(function() { funarr('2') })
  .add('#Button1').mouseup(function() { funarr('0') });


function funarr(value){
    arrow = value ;
    outputEl.html('<b>Result:</b> ' + arrow);
}
```

?